# Who killed My Java Infinite loop thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, memory-management, jvm, kafka-consumer-api

As the title suggested, I have some code wrapped in a `while(true)` infinite loop, and all of them are fully caught by `try` and `catch` block. This thread is started in the main method, however, after long run, this worker thread is vanished mysteriously when I check using the jstack and causing work accumulated.

Below is my code:

```
public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            // Consumer consumes from Kafka server
            Global.KAFKA_METRIC_DATA_CONSUMER.consume(topic, handler);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("Kafka consumer process was interrupted by exception!");
        } finally {
            try {
                // Prevent restart too often
                Thread.sleep(30 * BaseConst.SECOND);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For my understanding, this structure will keep the thread running so is the consumer. Even if the consume() methods failed, it will restart infinitely. However, as I mentioned above, the whole thread disappear silently without any error log. Could anyone provide some clue please?

Some more information that might be helpful:

1. I have checked the consume method will never shutdown the consumer
   nor close the socket to the server. It will continuously try to
   connect server after fail.
2. I analysed the java heap dump, and I found there is a memory leak
   somewhere else in the project, causing memory occupation extremely
   high and the gc very often. However, the main method is still
   running.

Comment: You shouldn't use `Thread` directly; use an `ExecutorService` instead (probably even a `ScheduledExecutorService` in your case). Also, catching `Exception` is a bad idea in general -- you even catch everything `RuntimeException`. But... You don't catch `Error`s. What probably happens here is that you have triggered, say, an `OutOfMemoryError` which triggered the loop to end. More generally you should review your design.

Comment: Also, instead of your `Thread.sleep()`, you could use `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30L)`; but do use a `ScheduledExecutorService` instead anyway.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[OutOfMemoryError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html) is not an Exception. It's an Error derived from Throwable.

If that was thrown somewhere in your `consume(topic, handler)`, finally would still be called, delaying the inevitable some 30s... but after that the error would be passed upward and your loop would be terminated.

Comment: Thanks! That explains a lot. However, I'm confused by where will OutOfMemoryError be thrown? Will it be thrown anywhere in the code, randomly? I have played around with this project several times, and it occurs that every time only this thread is killed. That must be some reason, right?
And, could you explain more why Error should not be caught? How should we deal it "properly"? @RealSkeptic

Answer (score 1):

You are catching `Exception` so there's a chance that a `java.lang.Error` or a `java.lang.Throwable` is being thrown (eg [OutOfMemoryError](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/OutOfMemoryError.html))

If you really want to catch everything, you'll need to catch `Throwable` and not just `Exception` subclasses.

Comment: Don't catch `Throwable`. At least not inside this loop. It can lead to serious trouble. An `Error` should be dealt with properly, not just ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Your thread is probably killed by an error.

**An error is not an exception!** But they both extend [`Throwable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html)

Add another catch block that catches errors.

Throwable should never be caught, because errors require a different handling than exceptions